# How can I open a PDF file via my Android app?

Tags: android, android-intent, path, launching-application

I want to open a pdf file via an Android app. So far I have written the following code:

```
public class PdfopenActivity extends Activity {
    String selectedFilePath;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button btnOpen=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        btnOpen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Sample.pdf is my file name it is in /Root/Download/Sample.pdf 
                // path of the file

                File file = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Sample.pdf");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/pdf");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The pdf is `175kb` and I can open the file directly on my Galaxy Tab2 tablet, but when I run my my program to open it I get the error:

> An Error Occurred while opening the document.

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?
.

Comment: In both devices same PDF viewer installed?

Comment: make sure the pdf is situated at correct place in sdcard.if it is inside any folder than it is also to be included

Comment: By writing Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Sample.pdf" it shows that it is not in any folder but inside sdcard

Comment: /Root/sdcard/Download/sample.pdf

Comment: you must have to include download as /sdcard/download/sample.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out:

```
        Button btnOpen=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnOpen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                File file = new File("/sdcard/sample.pdf");

                if (file.exists()) {
                    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                    try {
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } 
                    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks for ur reply when iam putting this no action performed when i click on the button ?

Comment: i have made comments under ur questions see it

Comment: thankd for ur reply my pdf file location is   /Root/sdcard/Download/sample.pdf